# 4 bit hash from String in Swift

Tags: swift, hash, swift4

I have a 16 elements array that holds 15 colors that match my UI. Based on the user’s entered name (Firstname + Lastname) I want to select a color (index in array of 0-15). So not a random color, but a color thats always the same for the same name. I figure I need to calculate a 4bit (0-15) hash of the String. Researching the web I find lots of hashing libs for eg MD5. But what would be a good approach to get a 4bit hash number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possible solutions. You just need a way to hash your string into a number and then use `% 16` to reduce that final number into an index in your desired range.

Here's one approach that sums up the bytes of the string's UTF-8 encoding to come up with a total and then uses `% 16`.

```
extension String {
    var fourBitHash: Int {
        return self.utf8.reduce(0) { $0 + Int($1) } % 16
    }
}

let colorIndex = "John R Smith".fourBitHash
print(colorIndex)
```

This will always give the same result for a given string.

Comment: Great solution also very swifty:) just wondering if there is a std hashing function we could use. But this will definitely work!

Comment: There is the standard `hashValue` from the `Hashable` protocol but its value is not guaranteed to be consistent across executions of an app.

Comment: @maddy woaw I did not know that! Just wondering how this is calculated then by Apple... some sort of app instance id is used?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you want the color to stay the same for particular name but also be able to distinguish those 16 colors.

As far as the alphabet consists of 26 letters, you need to pack those different combination in 16 colors.

There's practically no way to get such a hash without collisions (no way to encode even 1 letter in 4 bits) so you would want to get different colors for 2 different names (whilst they both are presented somewhere where you show them or whatever) but hash will give you the same color.

Random is probably not a bad way at all. Or having constantly growing dictionary for name-color (which can be stored on disk). Choose for yourself.

Comment: There's far more than 26 letters. Names will be in upper and lower case letters and names can be in many other languages and alphabets than plain English.

Comment: @rmaddy i was not going into upper-lower-chinese-whatever thing because 26 is enough to understand there'll be repeating colors.

Comment: Nothing about the question precludes multiple strings (names) from having the same color. The requirement is that a given name always evaluates to the same hash.